# Custom Grails Constraint doesn't seem to work

Tags: grails, grails-constraints

I have been trying to create a custom constraint in a Grails Project (see constraint code below).

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.AbstractConstraint
import org.springframework.validation.Errors

class BuscaConstraint extends AbstractConstraint {

    public static final String CONSTRAINT_NAME = "busca"

    protected void processValidate(Object target, Object propertyValue, Errors errors) {
    }

    boolean supports(Class type) {
      return type && String.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    String getName() {
      return CONSTRAINT_NAME;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this constraint doesn't actually validates anything. Instead, it's just a *flag* to customize the property's rendering in the scaffolding generation.
After creating the class above, I added the following line in the file Config.groovy:

```
ConstrainedProperty.registerNewConstraint(BuscaConstraint.CONSTRAINT_NAME, BuscaConstraint.class)
```

..and added this constraint to a class's property:

```
class ThatClass {
  def someProperty
  static constraints = { someProperty (unique:true, busca: "nome") 
}
```

However, if I try to get the result of the expression 
`ThatClass.constraints.someVariable.getAppliedConstraint("busca")`,
all I get is `null`.

I based my approach in some blog posts such as [this one](http://blog.swwomm.com/2011/02/custom-grails-constraints.html) and from a [constraint in Grails' github repo](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/bcb843a03b67f8d51920eaef847efd976babdc4d/grails-validation/src/main/groovy/org/grails/validation/EmailConstraint.java)(however I can't see how they are configured there).

What am I doing wrong?
Has the configuration of Grails' custom constraints changed recently?

Answer (score 0):

It looks your constraint is good. I use something very similar in my [Url Without Scheme Validator Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/url-without-scheme-validator), in class [UrlWithoutSchemeConstraint](https://github.com/MarcinOS/url-without-scheme-validator-plugin/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/urlWithoutSchemeValidator/constraints/UrlWithoutSchemeConstraint.groovy) and it works like a charm in recent Grails (2.3.x, 2.4.x).

However, I never tried to access it at runtime, so I'd try to investigate this area. For example, have you tried `ThatClass.constraints.someProperty.busca`?

Comment: In grails 4 To access as an example the matches constraint of a domain class it be `ThatClass.constrainedProperties.someProperty.matches` - I think it had been as per answer `constraints` now changed  in more recent times to `constraintProperties`

Answer (score 0):

I am also using my constraint as a tag in a Grails 2.4.4 project. The constraint can be accessed with the following code:

```
domainClass.constraints[p.name].getMetaConstraintValue("encodeAsRaw")
```

Where p.name is the property name and "encodeAsRaw" is the name of my constraint. I am using this code successfully in a couple of .gsp files.

If just using as a tag, you don't even need to create a custom constraint class and register it. It's enough just to check for its existence with the getMetaConstraintValue method.

For completeness, here is my constraint definition in my domain class:

```
myProperty(nullable:true, blank:true, unique:false, maxSize:1000, encodeAsRaw:true)
```